# on using "to denote" to define a term

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality, terminology

I want to define few terms but not sure how to use denote. For example:

> We use the term XYZ to denote websites consisting of ...

Is the above correct statement?

Comment: What does your dictionary have to say on that...?

Comment: Yes, it's fine - although there's nothing wrong with the simpler term *mean*.